# Button is not visible

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create a button from C# code at the opening of the form, yet it doesn't show on the screen. My code is just below.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Size = new Size(btnWidth, btnHeight);
    b.Location = new Point(30 , 30 );
    b.Visible = true;
    b.Text = "X";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you didn't add the `Button` to your `Form`'s `ControlCollection`. You need the [`Control.ControlCollection.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx) method. So add this line at the end of your code:

```
Controls.Add(b);
```